# WP_Query in category and random posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a "related posts" kind of plugin and want to show random related posts in specific category. That's the easy part and I'm doing it like this:

```
$args=array(
    'category__in' => $categories,
    'showposts' => $post_count, 
    'orderby' => 'rand',
);

$related_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Now my problem is that the post count is not always met and I want the query to always return the number of posts specified.

For example, my $post_count is 4 but the category we're querying only returns 2 posts. I want the rest to fill in with random posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to check if the number of returned posts is equal to 4. If not, create another query for posts from all categories *except* the ones in `$categories`. The count there should be `(4 - the number of results from the first query)`. This way, you'll always get 4 posts, and posts from the specified categor(y/ies) would show up first.

Comment: Thank you. I'm accepting this answer and this is what I ended up using but now I'm really curious if you can do it in a single query.

Comment: @ozzysong I assume it is not, as SQL queries are boolean. They either include something in the result set, or exclude it. 
Unless of course WordPress has implemented something like this in the WP_Query object, but they would probably do it in a similar way to my answer.

Comment: @ozzysong Also, I assume this situation only happens rarely (for instance on a very new blog), so then it is not that big of a deal if an extra query needs to be executed. If you have many categories that contain only a few posts, it is generally a better idea to use tags instead. Not that that would solve your problem, though ;)